# Java LocalDateTime/ OffsetDateTime to Swift 4

Tags: java, swift, datetimeoffset, localdate

What's the equivalent of LocalDateTime and OffsetDateTime in Swift 4?

I am trying to encode Java dates and decode them in Swift using Json.  It seems like there is only one Date object in Swift.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Updated.  Does this help?

Comment: It might be good to have a (simplified) example of what your JSON looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift uses the `Date` struct to store a point in time. This is always stored in `UTC`. If you want the local date time, you either work with `Calendar` or with `DateFormatter`, like in this example:

```
import Foundation

let date = Date();

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium 
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none // ignore date
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 2*60*60)
let localDate = dateFormatter.string(from:date)

print("UTC Time: \(date)")  // 2018-10-18 08:15:07 +0000
print("Local Time: \(localDate)") // 10:15:07 AM
```

There are multiple ways to convert `Date` into someting local, just use a search engine of your choice

Comment: The `LocalDateTime` class in Java represents a date and a time-of-day without any concept of time zone nor offset-from-UTC. So it does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline.

Comment: @BasilBourque I was talking about the Foundation `Date` class, not about any Java classes. `Date` in fact is a point in time.

Comment: That’s my point, the title of the Question asks partly about Java `LocalDateTime`. This Answer does not address that part.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java's LocalDateTime is "just a container" for storing local date and time values, I recently copied this idea from Java and created a Swift version: https://github.com/hoereth/LocalDateTime